# meta-ruby: how to dynamically call a scoped constant?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Say I have a class like:

```
class Person
  module Health
    GOOD = 10
    SICK = 4
    DEAD = 0
  end
end
```

I can reference such Health codes like: `Person::Health::GOOD`. I'd like to dynamically generate a hash that maps from number values back to constant names:

```
{ 10 => "GOOD",
   4 => "SICK",
   0 => "DEAD" }
```

To do this dynamically, I've come up with:

```
Person::Health.constants.inject({}) do |hsh, const|
  hsh.merge!( eval("Person::Health::#{const}") => const.to_s )
end
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a better/safer way to go about it. It's in a Rails app, and while it's nowhere near any user input, `eval` still makes me nervous. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Suppose `GOOD = 4`, `SICK = 4`, `DEAD = 0`, considering that hash keys must be unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`constants`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-constants) and [`const_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get) for this purpose.

```
ph = Person::Health # Shorthand
Hash[ph.constants(false).map { |c| [ph.const_get(c), c.to_s ] }]
# {10=>:GOOD, 4=>:SICK, 0=>:DEAD}
```

I added `false` to `.constants` to prevent including any inherited constants from included Modules. For example, without `false` the following scenario would also include a `5 => "X"` mapping:

```
module A
  X = 5
end

class Person
  module Health
    include A        
    # ... 
  end
end

Hash[ph.constants.map { |c| [ph.const_get(c), c.to_s ] }]
# {10=>"GOOD", 4=>"SICK", 0=>"DEAD", 5=>"X"}
```